# Animation Nodes Rotation Swing/Ticker

Tags: animation-nodes

I am no programmer by any means but have managed to get a bunch of gears to run on AN(Animation Nodes) and I would like to add a ticker with a swing as per the GIFF attached.
Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

I thought of using a some math nodes that would rotate the object once the input object gets to a certain rotation.[image]

Answer (score 2):

For a simple setup you can do something like this:

[image]

[image]